# using threads in QCustomPlot

Tags: multithreading, qt, qcustomplot

I've created a Dialog with 2 QCustomPlot widegets.
im trying to plot them both.

this is my code:

```
setData1(); //set points into widget1, no plotting
setData2(); //set points into widget2, no plotting

std::thread a([this]()->void {ui->widget1->replot();});
std::thread b([this]()->void {ui->widget2->replot();});

a.join();
b.join();
```

i think its suppose to be very simple but the program has unexpecterdly finshed

any ideas??

Comment: Generally speaking, you can't update a `QWidget` from any thread other than that on which `main` is running.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: you can not update the GUI from a thread other than the main one, why do you need it? I do not think it's necessary. More information in http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html#gui-thread-and-worker-thread